# A tool for fixing things also being broken: Irony? Or a better term?

Tags: irony

*Concrete example:* A web site's feedback form for site errors is broken; so I can't use the feedback form to report that the feedback form is broken.

Is this Irony or some other English word?

Comment: Drive-by downvoting. I love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is ironic. It could also be *paradoxical*.

From [thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/paradoxical):

> **paradox**  *n.*
>
> 1. A seemingly contradictory statement that may nonetheless be true: the paradox that standing is more tiring than walking.
> 2. One exhibiting inexplicable or contradictory aspects: "The silence of midnight, to speak truly, though apparently a paradox, rung in my
>      ears" (Mary Shelley).
>
> Adj.  1.  **paradoxical** - seemingly contradictory but nonetheless
>   possibly true;
>
> *"it is paradoxical that standing is more tiring than walking"*